# Object not being updated correctly inside Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I believe this has to do with the way JS Closures work, but I am not totally sure.  I am using an AngularJS service to manage the life-cycle of a model that is used within my application.  The service uses a combination of `fetch()` and `save()` to run GET and POST requests get and update the model from an API.  After I `fetch()` the object, I attempt to place the result into an object sitting in the service where it can be fetched later on.  My problem, is that after a successful `save()`, I take the result and place it into the same object to essentially "update" the object that is on the client with the correct object that is on the server (hence the result of the POST is just an echo of the payload if all is successful).

The problem is that my object is not persisting, and all subsequent calls to `save()` contain a "stale" object that is not completely updated.

Here is my service:

```
app.factory('MailboxSubscription', function (API, $q, $stateParams, $rootScope) {

    var Subscription = null; //THIS IS MODEL THAT I TRY TO UPDATE CONSTANTLY
    var isBusy = false;
    var service = {};
    var deferred;

    var defaultFailure = function(res){

    }

    service.fetch = function (success, force, failure) {

        if(!failure){ failure = defaultFailure;}


        if(isBusy){
            deferred.promise.then(success, failure);
            return deferred.promise;
        }else{
            deferred = $q.defer();
        }

        if(Subscription && !force){ // ONCE THE MODEL HAS BEEN FETCHED ONCE, IT STAYS IN MEMORY AND ALL SUBSEQUENT CALLS WILL SKIP THE API CALL AND JUST RETURN THIS OBJECT
            deferred.resolve(Subscription);
        }else{
            //Make the API call to get the data

            //Make the API call to get the data
            if(typeof(success) === 'function'){
                var ServiceId = $stateParams.serviceId;
            }else{
                var ServiceId = success;
            }

            isBusy = true;
            API.Backups.O365.Exchange.get({id : ServiceId || $stateParams.serviceId}, function(res){
                isBusy = false;
                if(res.success){
                    Subscription = res.result;  // ON A FIRST-TIME FETCH, THIS API CALL IS USED TO GET THE MODEL
                    deferred.resolve(Subscription);
                }else{
                    deferred.reject(res);
                }
            }, function(res){
                isBusy = false;
                deferred.reject(res);
            });
        }

        deferred.promise.then(success, failure);

        return deferred.promise;

    }

    service.save = function(success, failure){
        if(!failure){ failure = function(){};}
        if(!success){ success = function(){};}

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        API.Backups.O365.Exchange.update({id :$rootScope.ServiceId || $stateParams.serviceId}, Subscription, function(res){
            if(res.success){
                Subscription = res.result;  // AFTER AN UPDATE IS MADE AND THE OBJECT IS SAVED, I TRY TO SET THE RESULT TO Subscription.
                deferred.resolve(res);
            }else{
                deferred.reject(res);
            }
        }, function(res){
            deferred.reject(res);
        });

        deferred.promise.then(success, failure);

        return deferred.promise;
    }


    service.get = function(){
        return Subscription;
    }

    return service;


});
```

So the problem appears to stem from trying to use `Subscription` as a centralized resource for storing the model, but the model is not updating correctly.

Comment: Didnt get what the problem is? That object on client may be not the same as on server? You cant avoid it. And 'save' often contains not fully updated object...

Comment: Well yes of course.. I know how HTTP and API's work.  I FORCE the client to always be updated with what the server has because all calls (GET and POST) respond with the full `Subscription` object

Comment: The problem definitely has to do with the assignments not acting on the same place in memory.  The `Subscription = res.result` lines appear to assign to different variables in the closure or something and therefore are never updated correctly

Comment: I was able to "fix" it by re-assigning my controller's `$scope` variables after every save. Before I was assigning only after a fetch and then I expected the `$scope` to always be referencing the Subscription object, but it does not so I needed to re-assign the entire $scope to get it to work.. I still would like to know WHY tho

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have that Subscription model updated throughout the service, I'd suggested when you call `MailboxSubscription.fetch()` and `MailboxSubscription.save()`in your controller, you use `MailboxSubscription.get()` in the .`then(`) method of your calls.

```
// get initial value of Subscription model
$scope.Subscription = MailboxSubscription.get();


// let's fetch    
MailboxSubscription.fetch().then(
    // callback
    function() {
        // let's get the updated model
        $scope.Subscription = MailboxSubscription.get();
    }, 
    // errback
    function() {
        // handle error
    }
);

// let's save
MailboxSubscription.save().then(
    // callback
    function() {
        // let's get the updated model
        $scope.Subscription = MailboxSubscription.get();
    }, 
    // errback
    function() {
        // handle error
    }
);
```

Also, I've created a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGertrudes/0o6g2uyv/11/) simplifying your use case. It works fine. Maybe there is something that can be gleamed from that (I am using $timeout to spoof your API calls).